# Weighted Classification Metric for Multi class classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, metrics, multiclass-classification

I have a multi-class classification problem with the classes `X-Small`, `Small`, `Medium` and `Big`.

I have the following **requirement**:

[image]

#### Summary:

- Predicting a `X-Small` as `X-Small` is **GOOD**
- Predicting a `X-Small` as `Small` is **OK**
- Predicting a `X-Small` as `Medium` is **BAD**
- Predicting a `X-Small` as `Big` is **BAD**

Similarly

- Predicting a `Small` as `X-Small` is **OK**
- Predicting a `Small` as `Small` is **GOOD**
- Predicting a `Small` as `Medium` is **OK**
- Predicting a `Small` as `Big` is **BAD**

Similarly

- Predicting a `Medium` as `X-Small` is **BAD**
- Predicting a `Medium` as `Small` is **OK**
- Predicting a `Medium` as `Medium` is **GOOD**
- Predicting a `Medium` as `Big` is **OK**

Similarly

- Predicting a `Big` as `X-Small` is **BAD**
- Predicting a `Big` as `Small` is **BAD**
- Predicting a `Big` as `Medium` is **OK**
- Predicting a `Big` as `Big` is **GOOD**

**Question**

- What is the ideal classification metric to use?
- What is the ideal loss function to use?

Comment: This is not a *programming* question, hence it is off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: @desertnaut: I actually posted the question in data science stack: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/114423/weighted-classification-metric-for-multi-class-classification and I didn't receive any response (till now). That community is not super active.

Answer (score 1):

There are different alternatives, which are basically based upon binary 2x2 contingency tables:
For multiclass classification, the easy way to go is to use:

- accuracy = sum(diag(matrix))/sum(matrix). The closest to one the better.
- But you can also use it for each class:

  - Re-label to make a 2x2 contingency table, like the class of interest against the rest, and calculate every available index, sensibility, specificity, accuracy, etc. To create the intra-class metrics.
  - Then create the global metric by the mean of the metric by the number of classes. This is usually called the macro-sensibility, macro-xxxx measurement.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you answered is a typical multi-class classification metric. What I need is much more critical penalization based on prediction extremes. 

i.e. In your case - I believe: Predicting `Small` as `Medium` and `Small` as `Big` will result in same score.

Comment: Ah, you can first multiply your confusion matrix by a weighted matrix where you have the principal diagonal is 1 (good), then x.x for OK and y.y for Bad, before calculating the metrics. So, depending on the x.x and y.y values you will add more/less weight to what you are looking for

Comment: I just tried it with weights 1, -1, -2 and it is working. Please add your comment to your answer so that I can upvote and accept it as **Answered**.